# How can I get max sum in table with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL database with a table like this:

```
ObjID Rating
123   1
333   0
123   0
123   1
567   1
```

An Ojbect ID can show up in the table multiple times with different ratings, I need a way to select a "distinct" ObjID check all of its ratings and compare that to all other "distinct" ObjIDs and compare those ratings. In the end I should have the 1st - 3rd ObjIDs with the over all highest ratings, in this example 123, 567 and 333 would be printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the rating of each object is the total sum of all ratings for that object in the table?

```
SELECT ObjID, SUM(Rating) AS TotalRating
FROM ObjectTable
GROUP BY ObjID
ORDER BY SUM(Rating) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Yes, but when I remove LIMIT 3, and add:                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
echo $row['ObjID'];
} it only prints 1 result.

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){ echo $row['ObjID']; }` should be better. Maybe you have only 2 rows?

Comment: As ring0 mentioned, are there only two unique object ids in the table?  What happens when you run that query in the MySQL console?